# Setting up Ubuntu server with firewall - do I need 2 NICs?

Tags: networking, server, firewall

Assume a LAN where 4 port ADSL Router, Server and PCs all connect to a network switch. Apart from working with the server, the workstations must have restricted access on what sites they can use. For example, I don't want the PC users to go on YouTube or FaceBook.

If I'm to setup a server for my LAN, do I need to have 2 NICs on the server? BTW, I'm thinking of using Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 for the server so that the desktop can also be used by another user.

So is the above setting possible or will it be necessary to use 2 NICs and physically connect only the server to the router?

Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I have an Ubuntu Server with Zentyal 3.0 installed on top, and in order to function as a Firewall, it requires two NICs. I assume this to be true in all cases (one in, one out) but I only have experience with my own configuration. Hope this helps :-)